# How to check disabled item in a <select>

Tags: cypress

Im trying to write a test that should check if an item in a  is disabled.

The item is visible, but not clickable, and that's correct. But Im not sure how to write my test to make it pass this as correct.

My current test will fail due to not being able to select 'Create new'.

```
it('Not clickable', function() {
        cy.visit(url);
        cy.get('#dropDownMenu').should('be.visible', 'Choose...');
        cy.get('#dropDownMenu').select('Create new').should('be.disabled');
    })
```

How can I make my test find and understand that my select('Create new') should be disabled and that this is correct?

Here is the dropdownmenu html:

```
<select name="#dropDownMenu" id="dropDownMenu" 
data-ng-change="$ctrl.onSelectdropDownMenu()" 
data-ng-model="$ctrl.handleDropDownMenuOptions.val" 
class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched">  

<option data-ng-repeat="option in 
$ctrl.handleDropDownMenuOptions.availableOptions" 
data-ng-disabled="option.disabled" 
value="NOT_SELECTED" disabled="disabled">Choose...</option>

<option data-ng-repeat="option in 
$ctrl.handleDropDownMenuOptions.availableOptions" data-ng- 
disabled="option.disabled" value="NEW" disabled="disabled">Create 
new</option>
```

Comment: Can you post the dropdown html code ?

Comment: it wont be able to select a disabled option from a dropdown.. because it is disabled ;) You have to get the item and assert the property, just that. Don't actually select it.

Comment: @voy yeah, thats what I thought. How can I get the item since its in a <select>. From my understanding is that I can't use a cy.get to get that? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved it:

```
cy.get('#dropDownMenu').get('[value="NEW"]').should('be.disabled');
```